# Grails unique test fails?

Tags: testing, grails, unique

I am trying to create a test in grails to ensure indeed that the unique:true constraint works, here's my class and test file:

package edu.drexel.goodwin.events.domain

class UpayConfig {

```
String name
String siteId
String postingCode

static constraints = {
    name(blank:false, maxSize:50)
    siteId(blank:false, unique:true)
    postingCode(blank:false)
}
```

}

package edu.drexel.goodwin.events.domain

import grails.test.*

class UpayConfigTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {
    protected void setUp() {
        super.setUp()
    }

```
protected void tearDown() {
    super.tearDown()
}

void testCleanUpayConfigValidates() {
    mockForConstraintsTests UpayConfig
    def cleanUpayConfig = create()
    assertTrue cleanUpayConfig.validate()
}

void testUpayConfigSiteIdMustBeUnique() {
    mockForConstraintsTests UpayConfig
    def upayConfigOne = create()
    def upayConfigTwo = create()
    assertFalse upayConfigOne.validate()
    assertFalse upayConfigTwo.validate()

    upayConfigTwo.siteId = '81'
    assertTrue upayConfigOne.validate()
    assertTrue upayConfigTwo.validate()
}

UpayConfig create() {
    def upayConfig = new UpayConfig(
                    siteId: '82',
                    name: 'SMT - Workshops',
                    postingCode: '6'
            )
}
```

}

But that second test fails, the upayConfig variables both return true for .validate() even though I am telling them both to have the same siteId...

I have a feeling this has something to do with the fact that these aren't being placed in the database, just being stored in memory?

All  help is much appreciated, thank you.
-Asaf

Answer (score 5):

The uniqueness will be at the database level.  You're never saving the domain, so as far as upayConfigTwo is concerned, it is unique.  You'll need to do a regular mock and actually call save() on upayConfigOne.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you.  I looked up this website: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails10209/index.html and it had a section called "Testing the unique constraint with mockForConstraintsTests()" so following it I modified my test to be as follows and it passed correctly:

```
void testUpayConfigSiteIdMustBeUnique() {
    def upayConfigOne = create()
    mockForConstraintsTests(UpayConfig, [upayConfigOne])
    def upayConfigTwo = create()
    assertFalse upayConfigTwo.validate()
    assertEquals "unique", upayConfigTwo.errors["siteId"]

    upayConfigTwo.siteId = '81'
    assertTrue upayConfigTwo.validate()
}
```

Thank you for your help,
-Asaf